# Hibernate natural Id and 2nd level cache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I am trying to use Hibernate 4 with ehcache. My entities has several Id fields which are not primary keys in my DB.

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "tbl_a")
public class A {

  @Id
  private Integer uniqueId;

  @NaturalId
  private Date insertDate;

  @NaturalId
  private Integer businessId;

  ...

}
```

I want this entity to be cached, but it is cached by the `@ID` field and not by the combination of the `@NaturalId`s

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks,
Idob

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `insertDate` and `businessId` into a [composite key](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-hibernatejpa/). Objects, loaded via `session.load(...)` can be stored in 2nd level cache.